# How can I reset password in django by sending code to the user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I implement password reset in django, in a safe and secure way by sending a code to the user's email/phone?
I emphasise that I want to do this by sending a code to the user, not a link or anything else.
Something like what microsoft or google accounts does.

I've searched a lot for this problem but I've never found a proper solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "_not a link or anything else._", a link is also basically a code anyway, if you use the builtin [PasswordResetView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) it basically generates a token which is one time use and also expires in [PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout) seconds (3 days by default)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat for some reasones I need to do that in the way I've described. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure, but I think you can do it with [django-phone-verify](https://github.com/CuriousLearner/django-phone-verify)
The example on the website is about first authenticating, but modules API can be reused/extended.